# About heteroskedasticity form

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity

While studying Heteroscedasticity, I got a question about its form. Usually it is written by $$
Var(\epsilon_i | x_i) = \sigma^{2}_i = \sigma^{2}h_i^{2} = \sigma^{2}\exp(z_i' \alpha)
$$
where $z_i$ and $\alpha$ are vector.

Here is my question. Does $Var(\epsilon_i | x,y) = \sigma^{2}\cdot(\alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 y^{2})$ form of Heteroscedasticity also make sense?

It will be nice if anyone can explain why it can also be Heteroscedasticity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my understanding, the first equation you wrote imposes the restriction that variance is always nonnegative; while the second equation you wrote did not. The second one can potentially give you negative fitted value for the conditional variance, which is undesirable I guess.

Comment: it's not just undesirable, but not possible.

Comment: @gunes it is not possible since the variance can have negative value?

Comment: variance is always non-negative.

Comment: @gunes Yes, I meant that the variance can have negative value in that form, so it is not possible. It might confused you. Anyway thanks

Comment: @gunes Yes, variance by definition should be nonnegative is exactly what I meant by saying the second specification allowing variance taking negative fitted value is undesirable. This is similar to the difference between logistic regression and linear probability model.  Probability by definition is always nonnegative. Logistic regression always gives you nonnegative fitted value for the probability of being 1, while linear probability model can give you negative fitted value for that probability at some value of the regressors.